# How To stream.publish Within a Profile Tab

Tags: facebook, canvas, tabs, publish

I have successfully setup an iFrame based App using the Javascript SDK, and we are trying to enable it on a Page Tab.

It seems Facebook has changed some things lately, because the app breaks when added to the Page Tab. I even went as far as making sure that all external scripts were included in the main index.php file, and that the body tags were taken out.

No, I'm trying to find out if it is even possible to use methods such as the stream.publish within a Profile Tab at all.

It seems like it isn't. As far as I can tell, you can no longer use any social methods on the Profile Tab.

Here were two related articles on the subject:

insidefacebook.com/2010/08/19/facebook-moving-toward-iframes-over-fbml-for-canvas-apps-and-page-tabs/

-and-

developers.facebook.com/roadmap

If anyone can confirm or deny this, it would be a huge help. The Facebook docs are just all over the place.

Here's a link to the working App Canvas as it stands now: http://apps.facebook.com/votetesting/

Comment: BTW, I've seen other apps that are on a Profile Tab that are using stream.publish correctly. For example, the Cosmopolitian page here (second one down) lets you publish your quiz results: http://www.facebook.com/Cosmopolitan?v=app_138844219488062 I just have no clue how they were able to do this, unless if the app is older, and we just don't have this option anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I know that on tab pages, you cannot do any JS until the user clicks on something first. Maybe that is the problem.

-Roozbeh